# Flutter Migrate old project to null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, dart3

I have an old flutter project it doesn't support null safety dart 3.0.
I want to migrate its to Flutter 3 and Dart 3 without manual change variable in my model or class to null safety

I try to upgrade
environment:
sdk:
to support null safety and upgrade package it's work but all variable in my model or class getting error null safety

Comment: What's your question?  Yes, you have work ahead of you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the official migration guide provided by the Dart team.
You can find the migration guide [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).

steps:

downgrade flutter - dart pub get - dart migrate